# Show that the Yoneda embedding preserves exponential objects

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $\mathbb{C}$, let $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be its category of presheaves.

I want to show that the Yoneda embedding $y(A) = \hom(-, A)$ preserves exponential  objects from $\mathbb{C}$.

I tried playing around with adjunctions, but end up in quite a mess. Hence any help or insights is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can string together definitions adjunctions, and the occasional use of the Yoneda lemma to get (for any object $C$ in the category $\mathbb{C}$):
\begin{align*}
  y(B)^{y(A)}(C)
  &\cong \operatorname{Hom}(y(C), y(B)^{y(A)}) \\
  &\cong \operatorname{Hom}(y(C) \times y(A), y(B)) \\
  &\cong \operatorname{Hom}(y(C \times A), y(B)) \\
  &\cong y(B)(C \times A) \\
  &= \operatorname{Hom}(C \times A, B) \\
  &\cong \operatorname{Hom}(C, B^A) \\
  &= y(B^A)(C) \,.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice, very nice